# uncaughtException then appendFile on error will this cause problems? NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, error-handling

I'm curious about if since process.exit(1) is in the callback of a async 
operation, the appendFile, if where the original error happened will continue running and be in an unstable state. I tried to put the process.exit(1) inline with the fs but it wouldn't write.

better ways to create a error logged that will log on any error would be appreciated.      .

```
  const fs = require('fs');

  process.on('uncaughtException', e1 => {
    fs.appendFile('./logs/error.log', e1.stack, e2 => {
      //if (e1 || e2) console.log(e1,e2);

      process.exit(1)
    });

  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is, looks like your program will exit with an error code to the console every time it finishes with `fs.appendFile`. `process.exit` should kill anything else running once it hits that.

I'd probably do something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  fs.appendFile('./logs/error.log', err.stack, (fserr) => {
    if (err) console.log('FS ERROR', fserr); //now includes the fs error in log
    console.log(err); //maybe include error from uncaughtException?
    process.exit(1); //exit with error code
  });
});
```

Comment: Im actually not worried about the error from the file write, Im only concerned with the process exiting a bit after the error happens as opposed to at the same time

Comment: Then it depends on what else is going on. The process won't exit until the .appendFile is finished. You could try [`fs.appendFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_file_data_options) but if fs had an error trying to append to the file, it would exit without telling you the error.

Comment: Hm that should work actually because then this should happen before whatever else is going on, thanks !